# Handle UIButton click in a custom cell that is loaded in sections (where number of section is not defined. ie: taken dynamically)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, custom-cell

I am having a view controller where i want to load sections & the count for number of section is taken dynamically, ie: retrieved from database. Now, in each section am having 8 rows where row 2 to 8 are loaded with 5 buttons each.
I want that whenever a button on a cell is pressed a particular value is manipulated & displayed on the extreme right of that cell. Same thing should happen for all the sections.
.
My problem is that when i click a particular button on a cell of one section; some other button on the cells of other sections is selected as well.
.
Please help..

Answer (score 1):

you can get a section index as we as cell index as well at button tap Method using bellow code:-

```
-(IBAction)ActionBttonTap:(UIButton*)sender
{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:yourtableview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblHistoryYear indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
    NSString *strSection=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.section];
    NSString *strRow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"tag is %d   indexPath is  %d  section is %d",sender.tag,indexPath.section,indexPath.row);

}
```

Do not forget to set button tag at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like `self.yourbutton.tag=indexPath.row;`

Answer (score 0):

Implement `prepareToReuse` method in your cell, call `super` implementation of the same and then call `– removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method on the button.

As the cell will be reused, you have to remove the previous target set to the button before adding a new one.

Below is sample code

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [yourbuttonInstance removeTarget:self action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Passing NULL for action removes all the actions messages paired with the target and update the control events as per your requirement.

Comment: This might be correct. Can you please add some reference code or atleast any link that would help.